# Getting undefined index mysql session

Tags: php, mysql, forms, session, indexing

I am getting an error with the following code. I have two php files. One is a form which takes an input from a text field and I want it to be passed to the next file. This is what I have so far:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['submit']))
{
    $_SESSION['search'] = $_GET['patient_id'];
    header('Location:./reception_view_results.php');
}
else{
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Search Appointment</legend>
        <form method="GET">
            <label>Patient ID</label>
            <input type="text" name="patient_id"/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/>
        </form>
    </fieldset>
</body>
</html>
<?php 
} 
?>
```

And the subsequent page to which the value will be passed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>View Results</title> 
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
    session_start();

    include("connect.php");

    $search = $_SESSION['search'];

    if ($result = $db->query("SELECT nextapptdate, nextappttime, doc_id pt_id, pt_fname, pt_lname, ph_no 
    FROM patient 
    WHERE pt_id = $search
    ORDER BY pt_id;"))
    {
        // display records if there are records to display
        if ($result->num_rows > 0)
        {?>
            <fieldset>
            <legend><strong>Search Results</strong></legend>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Patient ID
                        <th>First Name
                        <th>Last Name
                        <th>Date of Birth
                        <th>Doc ID
                        <th>Phone No.
                        <th>Next. Appt.
                        <th>Time
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
                    {   
                        // set up a row for each record
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row->pt_id;
                        echo "<td>" . $row->pt_fname;
                        echo "<td>" . $row->pt_lname;
                        echo "<td>" . $row->ptdob;
                        echo "<td>" . $row->doc_id;
                        echo "<td>" . $row->ph_no;
                        echo "<td>" . $row->nextapptdate;
                        echo "<td>" . $row->nextappttime;
                    }?>
                    </tbody>
            </table>
            </fieldset>
        <?php
        }
    else{echo "No results to display!";}
    }
    ?>  
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried several things:
1) Changing from POST to GET.
2) Removing the action attribute from the form altogether.
3) Tried using the session variable directly.

I keep on getting an error on this line:

```
if ($result = $db->query("SELECT nextapptdate, nextappttime, doc_id pt_id, pt_fname, pt_lname, ph_no 
            FROM patient 
            WHERE pt_id = $search
            ORDER BY pt_id;"))
            {
```

It's because it doesn't understand $search.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I would try adding a [session_write_close](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) after assigning the value to session and before the redirect.

Comment: JazakAllah khayr for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a comma missing after doc_id. It should work like this (included some formatting)

```
SELECT
  nextapptdate,
  nextappttime,
  doc_id,
  pt_id,
  pt_fname,
  pt_lname,
  ph_no 
FROM
  patient 
WHERE
  pt_id = $search
ORDER BY
  pt_id
```

And looking through your first file: The global array `$_SESSION` does not exist until you call for `session_start` which is missing in the first file and will produce the error you have in your topic.

Comment: JazakAllah khayr! I was so tired of looking at this for about 2 days already. Made my night.